# Cyclohexene reduction reaction with hydrogen gas and ethanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, oxidation-state, cyclohexane

I have a following reaction (see below). I found the section of reduction and oxidation states in my book but there is nothing about cyclohexenes. I know that the double bond will be reduced in this reaction but what I have no idea what happens to those substituents. Why do they move around and what are their orientations? [image]

Comment: You know how reaction works, but not rotated molecule... Wow

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is a homework question, so I will not give a complete answer.

$\ce{H2/Pd}$ is a reducing agent, and it acts so by adding hydrogen to the double bonds. Alkenes are converted to alkanes. This proceeds via a concerted pathway, so rearrangements due to carbonation shifts do not occur. Now I think you can proceed from here.

As far as those substituents are concerned, *think carefully* on what would happen.

Answer (score -3):

The reaction with $H_2/Pd$ is one of the ways to reduce alkenes to alkanes. This takes place over the Palladium surface which has $H$ adsorbed on it. Hence we can think of cis addition in this case.[image]

It is clear through the mechanism that there is no formation of carbocations. So we need not worry of rearrangements. Now from the options up there it is quite clear I suppose. Hope it was helpful.